# Using XSLT to sort XML?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am displaying my XML using XSLT

My XML looks like this

```
    <main>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>Financial Accounting</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>1010</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>4</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ACCT</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>BUSN</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>Business</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>Managerial Accounting</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>1020</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>4</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ACCT</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>BUSN</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>Business</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>Computerized Accounting</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>1030</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>3</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ACCT</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>BUSN</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>Business</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>ELEM ACCT I ADV PLACE</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>1110</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>4</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ACCT</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>BUSN</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>Business</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>ELEM ACCT II ADV PLACE</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>1120</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>4</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ACCT</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>BUSN</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>Business</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>Personal Income Taxes</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>1500</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>3</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ACCT</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>BUSN</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>Business</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>Business Income Taxes</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>1510</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>3</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ACCT</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>BUSN</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>Business</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>PAYROLL</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>1600</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>2</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ACCT</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>BUSN</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>Business</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>Intermediate Accounting I</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>2010</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>4</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ACCT</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>BUSN</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>Business</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>Intermediate Accounting II</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>2020</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>4</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ACCT</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>BUSN</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>Business</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>MANAGERIAL ACCOUNTING</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>2030</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>4</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ACCT</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>BUSN</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>Business</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>ADMIN DCTN &#38; TRANSC</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>2540</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>5</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ADAS</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>OFAD</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>Office Administration</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>MS Office Applications II</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>2510</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>3</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ADAS</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>OFTD</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>Admsntrtv Office Technology</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION>This is an introductory course for beginners emphasizing correct pronunciation and basic vocabulary for practical use in everyday conversational situations and travel dialogues. Students with no previous study of the language are prepared to use and understand it within a limited context and basic structure.  Lecture: 3 hours</DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>Office Transcription II</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>2520</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>2</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ADAS</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>OFTD</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>Admsntrtv Office Technology</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>Office Tech &#38; Procedures II</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>2530</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>3</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ADAS</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>OFTD</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>Admsntrtv Office Technology</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>Administrative Office Mgt</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>2570</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>3</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ADAS</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>OFTD</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>Admsntrtv Office Technology</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>Office Admin Coop Ed I</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>2580</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>3</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ADAS</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>OFTD</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>Admsntrtv Office Technology</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>Office Admin Coop Ed II</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>2590</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>4</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ADAS</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>OFTD</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>Admsntrtv Office Technology</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>MS Office Applications III</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>2610</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>3</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ADAS</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>OFTD</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>Admsntrtv Office Technology</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>Office Admin Career Dev</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>2620</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>3</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ADAS</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>OFTD</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>Admsntrtv Office Technology</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>NURSING I</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>1010</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>7</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ADNU</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>ADN</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>AD Nursing</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    <TITLE>NURSING II</TITLE>
    <COURSE_NUM>1020</COURSE_NUM>
    <MIN_CREDITS>7</MIN_CREDITS>
    <MAX_CREDITS></MAX_CREDITS>
    <SUBJ>ADNU</SUBJ>
    <DEPT_ID>ADN</DEPT_ID>
    <DEPT>AD Nursing</DEPT>
  </DATA_RECORD>
</main>
```

My XSLT looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <?xml-stylesheet href="/_resources-2016/xsl/catalog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match ="/">
        <html>
            <head> 
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>          
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <xsl:for-each select="main/DATA_RECORD">
                                <!--<h2><xsl:value-of select="SUBJ" /> (<xsl:value-of select="DEPT" />)</h2> -->    
                                <ul class="verysimplelist">        
                                    <li style="font-size:150%; font-weight:400">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="SUBJ" />
                                    </li>

                                    <li style="font-size:150%; font-weight:400">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="COURSE_NUM"/>
                                    - </li>

                                    <li style="font-size:140%; font-weight:400; font-style:italic">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/>
                                    </li>

                                    <li style="font-size:150%; font-weight:400">
                                        (<xsl:value-of select="MIN_CREDITS"/>
                                    Credits)</li>
                                </ul>
                                <p>              
                                    <xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPTION" />
                                </p>
                            </xsl:for-each>               
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So using for-each works for me and I'm getting the desired output however I would like some additional functionality.

I would like them to be grouped still alphabetically but by `<DEPT>` with the dept name at the top of each group in a h2 tag or something like that. I can't seem to get this to work. Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You are looking for [Muenchian grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/muenchian-grouping).

Comment: Using the [exslt:node-set](http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html) makes life a *lot* easier.

Comment: I agree with zx485 that this sounds like a grouping issue. Can you add a couple more `DATA_RECORD`'s to your input and also add a desired output example? This will help us see what you're trying to group and sort. It should be pretty easy to get you an example of [muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

Comment: I edited in both `DATA_RECORD`s.

Comment: Sorry, I meant more `DATA_RECORD`'s with the same dept's so we could see the grouping. Right now there's nothing to group; they all have unique departments.

Comment: Right sorry... its for a college... so some there is a group of math, a group of engl, a group of biology etc.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, in XSLT 1.0, consider the Muenchian Grouping where you index the document by a certain key `<xsl:key>`, then generate groupings and map corresponding nodes under same group.

Below adds a `<h2>` tag for each *Dept* as headers above the output of other `<DATA_RECORD>` nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
     <?xml-stylesheet href="/_resources-2016/xsl/catalog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
     <xsl:output method="html"/>

   <xsl:key name="deptid" match="DATA_RECORD" use="DEPT"/>

   <xsl:template match ="/main">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="DATA_RECORD"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match ="DATA_RECORD">
     <html>
       <head> 
         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

       </head>
       <body>
           <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-12">
            <xsl:for-each select="self::node()[generate-id() = 
                                  generate-id(key('deptid', DEPT)[1])]">
                <h2><xsl:value-of select="DEPT"/></h2>

                <xsl:for-each select="key('deptid', DEPT)">                 
                    <!--<h2><xsl:value-of select="SUBJ" /> (<xsl:value-of select="DEPT" />)</h2> -->  
                    <ul class="verysimplelist">        
                          <li style="font-size:150%; font-weight:400"><xsl:value-of select="SUBJ" /></li> 
                          <li style="font-size:150%; font-weight:400"><xsl:value-of select="COURSE_NUM"/> - </li> 
                          <li style="font-size:140%; font-weight:400; font-style:italic"><xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/></li>            
                          <li style="font-size:150%; font-weight:400">(<xsl:value-of select="MIN_CREDITS"/> Credits)</li>
                     </ul>
                    <p>              
                         <xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPTION" />
                    </p> 
                </xsl:for-each>
           </xsl:for-each>
           </div>
           </div>
           </div>
         </body>
     </html>
   </xsl:template>


 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hmmm. What doesn't work? This example assumes root is `<main>` (which you do not include in post). In fact, your root may have namespaces. Please edit XML. Roots are very important in XML documents. Always include for full reproducible examples.

Comment: Hey Thanks again! I updated the XML... <main> is the root so that's weird.

Comment: Does anything have to change in the top of the XSLT in this part  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
     <?xml-stylesheet href="/_resources-2016/xsl/catalog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
     <xsl:output method="html"/>

Comment: @dbaker6 - If by "cant get it to work" you mean you get a bunch of `html` structures with empty `div`'s, you need to move the `html` up to the template that matches `main`. See here: http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZNA